# To clear the display after result when input is loaded again

Tags: calculator

Here after the result is loaded and try to input the next input it just get appended with the result, but the display should be cleared for the second calculation. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var arr=[];
var input=0;

function numberBtn(arg){
    if ( document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML ==="ERROR" || (document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML == "0"))
    {
        document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML = "";
    }

    input += arg;
    document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML += arg;   
}

function calculate(val){
    if(input !== 0){
        addToArr(input); 
    }

    var answer = val[0];           
    var divideZero =0;
    var i=2

    switch(arr[i-1]){
        case '+':
            answer= Number(val[i-2]) + Number(val[i]);
            break;
        case '-':
            answer-= val[i];
            break;
        case '/':
            if (val[i] == 0) divideZero = 1;
            else answer = answer / val[i];
            break;
        case'*': 
            //console.log(value,'before multiply');
            answer = answer * val[i];
            // console.log(val[i],'after multiply');
            break;
        case'%':
            if (val[i] == 0) divideZero = 1;
            else{
                var q= val[i-2]/val[i];
                answer= val[i-2] - (val[i] * Math.floor(q));
            }
            break;
        case'+/-':
            answer= -answer;
            break;      
    }

    if ( divideZero === 1) { 
        clearAll();
        document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML = "ERROR";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML = answer;
        input = answer;
        arr = [];
    } 
}

function addToArr(input){
    arr.push(input);
}

function clearAll() {
    arr = [];
    input = 0;
    document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML = "0";
}

function operatorBtn(arg){
    if (input !== 0) {
        addToArr(input);
        addToArr(arg);
        document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML +=arg;
        input = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more information about this program

Comment: After the getting result in the calculator, when I try to enter the next calculation, input just appends with the result. for eg: 4*3=12 ; if i want enter 7*5 after this, the first input taken is 127 and then the calculation goes on like 127*5=635. I just want to clear the result when I want to enter the input for next calculation. @JanČerný